# docker compose .env variables not set

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dotenv

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  compute:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "27030:27030"
    environment:
      - COMPUTE_HOST=$COMPUTE_HOST
      - COMPUTE_PORT=$COMPUTE_PORT
```

In my `.env` file I have the following:

```
COMPUTE_HOST="0.0.0.0"
COMPUTE_PORT=27030
```

This is to start up a flask api, but what I get when I run the container with:

`docker compose --env-file .env up --build`

or

`docker-compose --env-file .env up --build`

is this:

```
apv_compute-compute-1  | APV server starting on port None ...
apv_compute-compute-1  |  * Serving Flask app 'api' (lazy loading)
apv_compute-compute-1  |  * Environment: production
apv_compute-compute-1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
apv_compute-compute-1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
apv_compute-compute-1  |  * Debug mode: on
apv_compute-compute-1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
apv_compute-compute-1  |  * Restarting with stat
apv_compute-compute-1  |  * Debugger is active!
apv_compute-compute-1  |  * Debugger PIN: 483-995-326
```

The api insists on starting on `127.0.0.1:5000` suggesting that the environment variables are not set at all.

It also does not work if I change my compose file as follows:

```
    environment:
      - COMPUTE_HOST="0.0.0.0"
      - COMPUTE_PORT=27036
```

So likely not due to an issue with the .env file.  When running the app outside of docker it works perfectly fine.

*** UPDATE ***

The environment variables are actually set inside the container since `docker exec image_tag env` gives:

```
COMPUTE_HOST=0.0.0.0
COMPUTE_PORT=27030
```

Also, if I bash into the container, `echo $COPMUTE_PORT` gives the correct value.

So this is either `dotenv` not picking this up or the timing of when these variables are set leading to `dotenv` not getting them in time.

I have tried with both `load_env` and `dotenv_values`.

`Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086`

Comment: Try once using Curly braces around the env variable, something like `COMPUTE_HOST=${COMPUTE_HOST}`

Comment: @Sreevathsabr I have tried this already but this does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: I managed to find the reason for this to happen but not the root cause yet.  In the `Dockerfile` I start the api up with the `sudo` command which, for some reason, starts it up on the default port and host.  If I start the api without `sudo` it respects the environment variables set in `docker-compose.yml`.  Not sure if this is expected behavior so not posting it as an answer.

Comment: Are you sure `sudo` is required for running the container command? in this case, you may try running `sudo -E` instead? — in any case, maybe `sudo` is unneeded because the default user in the container already has admin rights, or, let me recall the [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user) to use a *non-privileged user* for running the dockerized web services that don't require privileges; see also [this article: 4. Don’t run containers as root](https://snyk.io/blog/10-best-practices-to-containerize-nodejs-web-applications-with-docker/).

Comment: @ErikMD no, `sudo` is not required.  I  did change this and the containers start up correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference: as mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928942/docker-compose-env-variables-not-set#comment127120395_71928942), the OP was using `sudo` for running the container command.

As a result, given `sudo` resets the environment by default (for security purposes, unless one uses the CLI option [`sudo -E`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)), the environment variables at stake are not preserved.

Note actually that in a Docker context, `sudo` is generally not required for running the container command because:

- either the default user in the container already has admin rights,
- or the container process just doesn't require privileges, in which case a [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user) amounts to using a *non-privileged user* for running the dockerized web service (see also [this blog article: `4. Don’t run containers as root`](https://snyk.io/blog/10-best-practices-to-containerize-nodejs-web-applications-with-docker/)).