# Docker Compose not reading env

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

This is an often asked question.  I have asked it previously but under different error conditions, yet I seem to be doing everything right as per all other posts on this topic so I revert to asking for advice.  Again.

I have the the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  projects:
    image: repo/apv_projects:2
    ports:
      - "27035:27035"
    environment:
      - JWT_SECRET_KEY_PROJECTS=${JWT_SECRET_KEY_PROJECTS}
      - PROJECTS_HOST=${PROJECTS_HOST}
      - PROJECTS_PORT=${PROJECTS_PORT}
      - PROJECTS_DB_HOST=${PROJECTS_DB_HOST}
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - projects_data:/app
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: repo/apv_projects_db:1
#    command: [--auth]
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/app/data/mongodb
volumes:
  projects_data:
  mongodb_data:
```

I have the following `.env` file:

```
PROJECTS_HOST='127.0.0.1'
PROJECTS_PORT=27035
PROJECTS_DB_HOST='mongodb'
PROJECTS_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=apv
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

I run the following command:

```
docker compose --env-file .\.env up --build
```

But the api (flask) starts up on `127.0.0.1:5000`.

The `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.9.12-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install sudo
RUN addgroup app && adduser -system app -ingroup app
RUN usermod -a -G sudo app
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER app

WORKDIR /app
RUN sudo mkdir data

COPY . .

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 api.py

EXPOSE 27017
EXPOSE 27035
```

The result is however that the environment variables in the container is not set.  when I run:

```
docker exec container env
```

I get the following output:

```
...
PROJECTS_HOST=
PROJECTS_PORT=
PROJECTS_DB_HOST=
...
```

Previously the error was that I started the api as `sudo` ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928942/docker-compose-env-variables-not-set)). This is no the issue now though.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve this issue.  It was related to line endings.  The `.env` file was created on a Mac so it had `CR` line endings but I was building on a `linux/amd64` platform so need to have `LF` line endings.  This caused the environment variables to be read as a single string and hence were not set at all.

Comment: which MacOS version are you using? It must be old, ever since OS X (which is basically BSD) it has used LR.

Comment: Using latest.  On M1 chip.

Comment: I had the same issue with a .env file created on an Intel mac not working on M1, changing the line endings to CRLF in VSCode worked